# sql I have error code : 1242 subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

```
select district,
    city,
    postal_code,
    (
        select sum(amount) as revenue
        from payment,
            address
        group by postal_code
        )
from sakila.address,
    sakila.city,
    sakila.payment
where address.city_id = city.city_id
group by district,
    city,
    postal_code
order by district,
    postal_code;
```

Above is my sql statement.  I have error code 1242.  I don't understand why I've got error.  I'm trying to calculate total revenue by postal code as well as populate district, city, postal code.

Could you tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong - Cross joins (twice), multiple rows from subquery in select, comma based joins. Please post sample data and desired output.

Comment: i think, the problem comes from ` (
        select sum(amount) as revenue
        from payment,
            address
        group by postal_code
        )`

Comment: @Salman - Even fixing that will not fix anything.

Comment: When I try only select sum(amount) as revenue from payment, address group by postal_code this part, it worked well.  the sum result is exactly what I want.  So, I added subquery.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Does payment contain the postal_code or are payment and address connected in another way?

Comment: No.  Payment table contains amount.  Address table contains postal code.   And these two tables do not connected.

Comment: Do payment and city have any fields in common?

Comment: City table contains city.

Comment: Does the payment table contain city?  Or even better, please edit your question to detail the structures of each table.

Comment: I added diagram.

Comment: Better.  I'll get stuck into it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
SELECT address.district,
       city.city,
       address.postal_code,
       SUM( amount ) AS revenue
FROM address
JOIN city     ON address.city_ID = city.city_ID
JOIN customer ON address.address_ID = customer.address_ID
JOIN payment  ON customer.customer_ID = payment.customer_ID
GROUP BY district, city, postal_code
ORDER BY district, postal_code;
```

Comment: You're welcome.  If you would like an explanation of my reasoning / answer, then please feel free to say so.

Comment: Is there possible way without using JOIN ON?

Comment: Yes, though they tend to be less efficient.  Did you have something in mind?

Comment: Can you tell me the way not using JOIN ON?  I want to learn even if it's not efficient.

Comment: Not really.  I've seen them around, but have never bothered learning them in this context as JOIN's have always seemed more efficient.  Sorry.

Comment: It's fine.  So, can you explain your code?  I don't understand why you use JOIN ON.

Comment: With your problem you are trying to form a temporary new  table of data using data in 4 different tables.  To do that we need to gather the data FROM the different tables together by specifying which table is related to another (JOINing them) and how they are related (our ON clause).  For example, City is related to Address by way of the city_ID field in each.  Once this data is gathered together (JOINed) you need to choose (SELECT) which fields you want in your temporary new table.  The JOINs correspond to the relationship lines from your diagram.

Comment: Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it a correlated subquery, not a grouped query.

```
select district,
    city,
    postal_code,
    (
        select sum(amount) as revenue
        from payment,
            address
        where postal_code = sakila.address.postal_code
        )
```

You also need a joining condition between the `payment` and `address` tables, otherwise it will create a full cross product between them. You also need a joining condition for the `payments` table in the main query.

You should learn to write queries with ANSI JOIN syntax, then you're less likely to forget to put the joining condition. And instead of using the correlated subquery, you can simply join with `payment`. I've used `LEFT JOIN` so you'll get `revenu = 0` when there are no customers or payments in a particular location.

The full query should be:

```
SELECT district, city, postal_code, IFNULL(SUM(amount), 0) AS revenue
FROM address AS a
JOIN city AS c ON a.city_id = c.city_id
LEFT JOIN customer AS cus ON cus.address_id = a.address_id
LEFT JOIN payment AS p ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
GROUP BY district, city, postal_code
ORDER BY district, postal_code
```

Comment: Your subquery has cross join same as OP.

Comment: I know, I just added something about that to the answer. WIthout knowing more about the tables I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I have tried but I got all the same values of sum column.

Comment: Did you add the missing join conditions?

Comment: I don't know how to use join.  sorry.

Comment: You should read a good SQL tutorial then. Don't ask me to recommend one, I don't know them.

Comment: Joining conditions are like `where address.city_id = city.city_id`. You need another condition for `payment`, to link it to the other tables.

Comment: I did like FROM sakila.address, sakila.city, sakila.customer where address.city_id = city.city_id AND payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id.  Then I've got error message "error code : 1054 unknown column 'payment.customer_id' in where clause

Comment: You left out `sakila.payment` in the `FROM` list.

Comment: I added sakila.payment.  But, I still have the same error.